# error in roc: Neural Network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, roc

I want to use neural network in R to predict the price of a car, having 144 independent variables. 
Below my code. Everything works fine, except the last 2 lines: AUC and plot.

This is the error I got:

**Error in roc(predNN, yTEST) : 
  Not enough distinct predictions to compute area under the ROC curve.**

I already computed the dependent variable as a factor, but this error remains.
How should I resolve this problem?

```
 allind <- sample(x=1:nrow(data_price2),size=nrow(data_price2))

 trainind <- allind[1:round(length(allind)/3)]
 valind <- allind[(round(length(allind)/3)+1):round(length(allind)*(2/3))]
 testind <- allind[round(length(allind)*(2/3)+1):length(allind)]

 BasetableTRAIN <- data_price2[trainind,]
 BasetableVAL <- data_price2[valind,]
 Basetablebig <-rbind(BasetableTRAIN,BasetableVAL)
 BasetableTEST <- data_price2[testind,]

 #Create a separate response variable
 yTRAIN <- BasetableTRAIN$Price
 BasetableTRAIN$Price <- NULL

 yVAL <- BasetableVAL$Price
 BasetableVAL$Price <- NULL

 yTEST <- BasetableTEST$Price
 BasetableTEST$Price <- NULL

 yBIG <- Basetablebig$Price
 Basetablebig$Price <- NULL

 yTRAIN <- as.factor(yTRAIN)
 yVAL <- as.factor(yVAL)
 yTEST <- as.factor(yTEST)
 yBIG <- as.factor(yBIG)

 if (require("nnet")==FALSE) install.packages("nnet") ; library(nnet)
 if (require("AUC")==FALSE) install.packages("AUC") ; library(AUC)

 size <- 5 #number of units in the hidden layer
 decay <- 0.1 #weight decay. Same as lambda in regularized LR. Controls for
               overfitting. 
 rang <- 0.5 #the range of the initial random weights parameter
 maxit <- 2000 #set high in order not to run into early stopping 

 NN <- nnet(yBIG ~ ., Basetablebig, size = size, 
       rang = rang, decay = decay, maxit = maxit,MaxNWts= Inf)

 predNN <- as.numeric(predict(NN,BasetableTEST,type="raw"))
 AUC::auc(roc(predNN,yTEST))
 plot(roc(predNN,yTEST))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are more than likely suffering from problems related to bad model. Look into the prediction of the model. Likely you might be having all 0's or 1's based on probability threshold  0.5. Neural net techniques are very susceptible of scale difference between different columns so standardization of data [mean =0 std =1] is a good practice. I would suggest you to use R function `scale()` for this. Please provide data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Someone else upvoted the answer. I tried to scale the basetable, but then this error occurs when running the neural network: Error in if (nconn[i + 1] == ns) cadd <- c(0, from) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. When having a look at the scaled basetable, some dummy variables now  have a lot of NA values, while others don't

Comment: Before all this code do `scale(data_price2)` thats it. I dont know how you got error you mentioned.

Comment: I scaled with scale(data_price2) in the beginning of the code. But still this error occurs: Error in roc(predNN, yTEST) : Not enough distinct predictions to compute area under the ROC curve.

Comment: length(yTEST) = 554

Comment: from figure it looks like all your prediction are below 0.5. Is this true? I mean if `length(unique(round(yTEST)))` is 1? If so is the case then simple rounding which is threshold=0.5 will yield all classification predicted classes 0. This is what error is all about.

Comment: yTEST <- as.numeric(yTEST)
length(unique(round(yTEST)))
[1] 448

Comment: > max(predNN)
[1] 0.4509424

Comment: the max 0.4509424 will also be rounded to 0. So essentially after rounding all your prediction are going for class 0. No other class. Thats what invoking this error. Read my original answer again.

Comment: I hope you have done `scale(data_price2)` after removing `yTEST`. Rest you are asking how to improve my model, please google and do few trials before asking that. You found the error root cause and now its time to improve.

Comment: still haven't found how to improve my model. I scaled (data_price2) after removing yTEST